# Checking if a value exist in Spymemcached without knowing the key

Tags: key-value, spymemcached

SpyMemcached : How to check if a value exist without knowing the key?

Thank you!

Comment: Let's rephrase the question: How do you find something when you don't know what you're looking for?

Comment: I agree with you, however, this is a constraint on me. I have an interface that I must implement and this case is one of the methods of the interface. So I wonder if there is any idea, or any combination, of methods...

Comment: One way or another, to search for something, you need to know what you are searching for. So in this case, the key must be coming from somewhere. :/

Answer (score 0):

Memcached is a cache and only supports set/delete/get type operations. You cannot create indexes on data in memcached and do searches on those indexes. If you want this functionality you should create an index in your database that maps values to keys.

Another option would be to look at Couchbase. It provides the same interface as memcached and has indexing capabilities. Note that Couchbase is more than just a cache however and it will also persist all of the data you set into it.